# Loops in a grouped by array of object by key

Tags: javascript, html

This is a small example. Below, I have a list of data that is `groupBy` the **type** . After it is `grouped`, this is where I needed help. I want to loop through each of the types for display like in the `html` (*you may need to view *full page* when you run the code snippet b/c the small preview is not showing it all*). Anything that would help me move forward, it would be greatly appreciated!

```js
  var samples = [
       {id: 1, name: "apple", type: "fruits"},
       {id: 2, name: "zucchini", type: "vegetables"},
       {id: 3, name: "orange", type: "fruits"}
  ];
  function groupBy(data, keyGetter) {
    const map = new Map();
    data.forEach((item) => {
      const key = keyGetter(item);
      const collection = map.get(key);
      if (!collection) {
        map.set(key, [item]);
      } else {
        collection.push(item);
      }
    });
    return map;
  }
  const grouped = groupBy(samples, sample => sample.type);
  console.log("grouped", grouped.get("fruits"));
  //It's unable to show the console log for just const grouped, so I'll attach the screenshot. I was able to see it in the inspect element window under 'console'
```

```html
  <!--This should be handled dynammically with js-->
  <section>
    <h2>Fruits</h2>
    <div style="background: tomato">
      <div>apple</div>
      <div>orange</div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h2>Vegetables</h2>
    <div style="background: tomato">
      <div>zucchini</div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

[image]

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you need help with. Just outputting html or something else?

Comment: @i-- I'm wanting to (1) loop through each of the object in the array after it is groupby based on type (screenshot) and (2) loop through the "value" array of each key, so it would output the html result (in the code snippet result) that I want. I'm stuck at (1) and prob be able to do (2) if (1) is resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

explanations are in code as comments

```js
  var samples = [
       {id: 1, name: "apple", type: "fruits"},
       {id: 2, name: "zucchini", type: "vegetables"},
       {id: 3, name: "orange", type: "fruits"}
  ];
  function groupBy(data, keyGetter) {
    const map = new Map();
    data.forEach((item) => {
      const key = keyGetter(item);
      const collection = map.get(key);
      if (!collection) {
        map.set(key, [item]);
      } else {
        collection.push(item);
      }
    });
    return map;
  }
  const grouped = groupBy(samples, sample => sample.type);
  const content = document.getElementById('content');
  
  grouped.forEach((value, key) => {
      const section = document.createElement("section"); //creating section tag
      const h2 = document.createElement("h2"); //creating h2 tag
      const type = document.createTextNode(key.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + key.slice(1)); //creating type name with first latter in upper case e.g Fruits
      const list = document.createElement("div"); // createing div which will contain list of type
      value.forEach(v => { // looping through each type list
        const text = document.createTextNode(v.name); // create name of list element
        list.appendChild(document.createElement("div").appendChild(text)); 
        list.appendChild(document.createElement("br")); //add new line between list elements
      });
      list.style.background = 'tomato';
      h2.appendChild(type);
      section.appendChild(h2);
      section.appendChild(list);
      content.appendChild(section);
  });
```

```html
  <div id="content">
  </div>
```